# Reg. Active Directory Integration with multiple OU Names :: OBIEE and Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, obiee

I have integrated OBIEE 11g with Active Directory successfully. The User Base DN is as follows : "OU = Departments, DC=[DC NAME],DC=[DC NAME]". However I would need to add another "OU = Branches" to it.

How can I do it.Do we have any 'OR' command to it? SO that, it traverses through multiple OU.

Comment: Did you give up on this?

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP query operator for OR is "|" - ref.http://www.ldapexplorer.com/en/manual/109010000-ldap-filter-syntax.htm

So (|(ou=A)(ou=B)(etc.))

Comment: Thanks for the response. Should I do it this way 
(OU=Departments,DC=al****c,DC=local)|(OU=Branches,DC=al****c,DC=local)

Comment: I found a way of doing this. by removing OU from the string. i.e., i just kept 'DC=al****c,DC=local'. However I couldnt get OR operator working for me.

Comment: (DC=al****c,DC=local)(|(ou=A)(ou=B)(etc.))